# Split data set and split ratio to get constant accuracy in Python

Tags: python, dataset, classification

```
def splitDataset(dataset, splitRatio):
  trainSize = int(len(dataset) * splitRatio)
  trainSet = []
  copy = list(dataset)
  while len(trainSet) < trainSize:
    index = random.randrange(len(copy))
    trainSet.append(copy.pop(index))
  return [trainSet, copy]
```

Using this function I get different accuracy every time I run the classifier.
It was caused by random function. So how can I split my data to get the unchanging accuracy?
this line is the main problem :

```
index = random.randrange(len(copy))
```

Comment: Use existing utilities like [`train_test_split` in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Comment: yes I've been learning about that but can't figure out how to implement it into my code.

Comment: Just look at the examples of that. If facing errors, then post the code here of what you are using, complete with error trace, and some data.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want reproducibility of the results. For that, use a seed for random values. So, the random numbers generated for splitting can be reproduced by using the seed again.

```
import random
random.seed(1)
```

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be getting different accuracies. That's kinda the point of machine learning. (It's really statistical learning.)

However, your question may really be that you want repeatability, so you want to pull the same subset of entries into your training set every time you run this. In that case, you should be able to specify the RNG seed and get the same sequence of pseudo-random lines to pull into your training set.

Still, that kind of predictability, while fine for demonstrating an algorithm, isn't what machine learning is about.